# Does your 401k provider stop you when you hit your max?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, contribution, limits

In general, I was wondering who is responsible for keeping track of when a normal, employer-sponsored 401k account has hit its pre-tax contribution limits for a year. I assume that, in the end, the individual is responsible for their tax-related activities, but I also know that there is typically a lot of legislation in place that prevents institutions from allowing individuals to do inappropriate tax maneuvers. It can only happen at one of three levels:

1. The 401K Provider - the 401k provider has all the information necessary to determine when an individual has put too many pre-tax dollars into an account and could stop them
2. The Employer - since HR/Payroll is responsible for deducting pre-tax contributions, they could easily stop the deductions when the yearly limit has been reached
3. The Individual - most of a 401k contribution is automated, but it could still be on the individual to reconcile everything at tax-time (though this could get very complicated, because tax-free growth occurred during the year); overall this seems like the sloppiest approach

So, at which level is this sort of limitation performed; or does it vary by provider and/or state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does your 401k provider stop you when you hit your max?

Here is a bogleheads discussion on the topic.  Apparently different employers do different things.

https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=133214

Some employers stop your contributions, some put the money in *after-tax* 401(k) contributions, and some stop their own matching contributions.

> The Individual

Only if you've had multiple jobs.  The second won't know how much you contributed to the first.

> though this could get very complicated, because tax-free growth occurred during the year

You seem to be implying that the capital **gains** which happen during the year affect the $19K you can **contribute** during the year.  That's not true.

Comment: Gains don't change the limit, but if the plan mistakenly accepts excess contributions (technically deferrals) they must remove and pay you (taxably) the excess _plus_ the portion of earnings on the account (interest, dividends, _or_ gains) allocable to that principal. (The same is true for IRA, where you are more responsible for avoiding excess contributions.)

Answer (score 2):

It happens. I maxed out my 401(k) contributions for 28 years and there was never an issue when the deposit hit the annual limit. Between the employer and administrator, it happens.